# issues looping back to start of program

Tags: python, file

I am having troubles looping back to the start of the program. I am asked to ask the user if they would like to enter another file, if they say yes it will bring them back to the start of the program to input a file name. When I do this, it just restates the previous file entered. I was wondering how to make it so it would ask for another file input. Here is my code:

```
def main ( ):
    file = input("Enter Name of input file: ")
    inputfile = open(file, "r")
    total = 0
    count = 0
    num_list = []
     #Read and display the file's contents
    for line in inputfile:
        number = int(line)
        total += number
        count += 1
        num_list.append(number) # append current number to the list

    max_number = max(num_list) # get max value from the list of numbers
    min_number = min(num_list) # get min value from the list of numbers
    range_of_list = (max_number - min_number)

    # close the file
    inputfile.close()

    while True:
        print("File Name: ",inputfile.name)
        print("Sum: ", total)
        print("Count: ", count)
        print("Average: ", total / count)
        print("Maximum: ", max_number)
        print("Minimum: ", min_number)
        print("Range: ", range_of_list)

        perform_again = input("Would you like to evaluate another file of numbers? (yes/no): ")
        if (perform_again == "yes"):
            continue
        else:
            break
main ( )
```

Comment: Your `while True` loop is only around the print statements, so that's all that'll get repeated. It seems like you'd want to wrap everything in the loop. Would that work, or is there some reason you're choosing to only loop the prints rather than the whole thing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `while loop` is wrapped around the print statements, so it will just keep printing again and again.

Have it at the start, like the following:

```
def main():
    while True:
        file = input("Enter Name of input file: ")
        inputfile = open(file, "r")
        total = 0
        count = 0
        num_list = []
        # Read and display the file's contents
        for line in inputfile:
            number = int(line)
            total += number
            count += 1
            num_list.append(number)  # append current number to the list

        max_number = max(num_list)  # get max value from the list of numbers
        min_number = min(num_list)  # get min value from the list of numbers
        range_of_list = (max_number - min_number)

        # close the file
        inputfile.close()

        print("File Name: ", inputfile.name)
        print("Sum: ", total)
        print("Count: ", count)
        print("Average: ", total / count)
        print("Maximum: ", max_number)
        print("Minimum: ", min_number)
        print("Range: ", range_of_list)

        perform_again = input(
            "Would you like to evaluate another file of numbers? (yes/no): ")

        if (perform_again == "yes"):
            continue
        else:
            break


main()
```